Error 400 when registering a webhook in #linkedin application
I have a problem activating the #linkedin webhook registration. I have tried everything as it is in the documentation, I have adjusted headers and configured URN encoded. However, when I request the subscription I get this error:
{ “message”: “Failed to create subscription. RestException{_response=RestResponse[headers={Content-Length=13373, content-type=application/x-protobuf2; symbol-table=\“https://ltx1-app92263.prod.linkedin.com:3778/partner-entities-manager/resources|partner-entities-manager-war--60418946\”, x-restli-error-response=true, x-restli-protocol-version=2.0.0},cookies=[],status=400,entityLength=13373]} “, ‘status’: 400 } 
The call I am making is:
curl --location --request PUT 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A219795302,user:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3Ad9qwE,entity:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A10291,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)' \ --header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202405' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0. 0' \ --header 'Authorization: ------' \ --header 'Cookie: lidc="b=TB16:s=T:r=T:a=T:p=T:g=5494:u=1341:x=1:i=1716582567:t=1716661312: 'v=2:sig=AQGzDlYwcKSrX9-utdno8q'; bcookie=“v=2&amp;5c5fe86f-d02c-48dd-855c-16”; Cookie_1=value' --data '{ “webhook”: “https://webhook. site/7c2b4a-d0bf-411c-96e6-914b” }'
Working the call with postman where the Content-Length and Host headers are generated automatically. I have seen in some forums that you must enter a webhook tab in the application UI, https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/219795302/Webhooks. However, this tab is not accessible from my app and I don't see any procedure to request the webhooks enablement. PS: I am Admin of the page and of the application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2024-05
Any clue what I am doing wrong or how to request to enable the webhooks tab?

The Webhooks tab is only enabled for applications with a use case for webhooks. For Lead Syncing use cases, webhook subscriptions must be created via the Lead Notification Subscriptions API and cannot be created via the UI
#linkedin Case No.: 240524-017378

